# Admin panel not working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently i am learning rails so i'm sorry for my bad knowledge and probably for a silly question. :)

I created a simple index page in a controller called pages.
      Inside index.html.erb i have a form where a user can sign up for a newsletter which is stored in @newsletter and i also have a variable called @title where title of the page is stored in database.

I want to create an administration panel available only for the owner of the website where he can access and display all newsletters, also i would like the owner to have the possibility to change the title.

Can i achieve that if i create another controller ?
What do you recommend, to keep the same controller for admin and pages or create a new controller for admin area ?

Also, one more question, when do i need to create a model? Everytime when i need a new table in database, isn't ?
I should have a single model for every controller or i can have more models and one controller?

Comment: Who will be logging into your site?  Admins AND users or just Admins?

Comment: @Peege151 - Just Admins.

Comment: Do they currently have a log-in?

Comment: It's just a presentation website for a nails company, users don't sign-in, log-in. The admin panel is going to be something like www.mydomain.com/admin

Comment: At the moment log-in is not implemented for admin area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any connection between pages and the newsletter?

If newsletter is not in a relationship with pages, then you can place the newsletter form in a partial and render it where you want.

This a possible db schema for you:

'Page.rb' model with the fields that you need like: title:string, slug:string (i prefer friendly_id), body:text...

'NewsletterEmail.rb' model with the fields that you need: email_address:string, name:string (optional), subscription_status:boolean (to track un-subscription)...

Every model needs a controller for you to track in admin.

For the front-end, you must setup a route like 'match: "/:slug" => "public#page"', where you can catch your page like @page = Page.friendly.find(:slug) and then assign the @title variable  @title = @page.title.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For your admin controllers pages_controller.rb and newsletter_emails_controller.rb you can use a before_action :check_admin_rights and define in application_controller.rb

def check_admin_rights
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') do |username, password|
username == 'admin' && password == 'password'
end
end